# How to access Session from other function

Tags: php, model, laravel-5

I am working in laravel 5.2. After login i am able to store variables into session.

```
$request->session()->put('adminSessionData', $sessionData);
$appAllSessionData = $request->session()->all();
```

This $appAllSessionData gives me all Session Data.

But on other function which is calling after login i am not able to get all Session.

I am calling in same way:

```
$appAllSessionData = $request->session()->all();
```

But it is not giving me Session variables of admin i.e., adminSessionData.

Comment: The put method stores a new piece of data in the session.

The push method may be used to push a new value onto a session value that is an array.